# For-Next Loop using end of month dates as iteration

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

I currently have a "For Next" loop that iterates through various years and I want to modify it to loop through dates, specifically the end of each month.  My generic code for the year loop is below.  Clearly looping through years is relatively easy since you have a start year, which is an integer, and the iteration is 1.  Now I want to modify the loop to iterate though various end of month dates.  For example, 1/31/2003, 2/28/2003, ......, 12/31/2007.  Also, note that for each iteration I create a new worksheet with the name of the current iteration as the name of the worksheet.  Again, this is relatively easy for a year but using a date with a "/" complicates things.  Does anyone have any ideas for creating a loop using end of month dates as well as creating sheets using dates?  I do have an array of the dates so the code could refer to the array within a sheet.  And the name of the sheet could be in any format.  For example, "mm-dd-yyyy".

```
Sub YearLoop()

    Dim FirstYr As Integer
    Dim LastYr As Integer
    Dim Sheetname As String
    Dim Counter1 As Single

    FirstYr = Sheets("Model").Range("ax15").Value
    LastYr = Sheets("Model").Range("ax16").Value

    Counter1 = 0

    For J = FirstYr To LastYr

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = J
        Sheetname = J

      'do stuff
      Counter1 = Counter1+1

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

The [DateSerial function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264202.aspx) produces the end-of-month date of the previous month when you give any month a day of zero.

```
dim m as integer
for m = 2 to 13
    debug.print dateserial(2016, m, 0)
next m
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this with a datediff to subtract a day, but this approach is easier.

Comment: No, if the day was 1 then it would be considered `01-Jan-2017` but with a day of zero it is `31-Dec-2016`. The OP should be able to easily nest this For ... Next inside the yearly one offered in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The characters that can't be used in sheet names are ASCII [`\/[]*:?`](http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/seven-characters-you-cant-use-in-worksheet-names), but you can use Unicode characters like [`⁄∕／`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation))

```
d = #1/31/2003#
While d <= #12/31/2007#
    Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = Replace(d, "/", ChrW(8260))
    d = d + 32
    d = d - Day(d)
Wend
```

**Update**

Or you can use Jeeped's answer like this:

```
For m = FirstYr * 12 + 2 To LastYr * 12 + 13
    Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = Replace(DateSerial(0, m, 0), "/", ChrW(8260))
Next
```

Comment: Great comments everyone.  Thank you so much!!!  Below is what I ended up doing.  And it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub ReadAndDisplay()

```
' Get Range
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Returns Calc").Range("C118:C319")

 ' Create dynamic array
Dim Arr() As Variant

' Read values into array from sheet1
Arr = rg

For Each mark In Arr

        Dim CurrentDate1 As Date, DimCurrentDate2 As String
        CurrentDate1 = mark
        CurrentDate2 = Replace(CurrentDate1, "/", ".")

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = CurrentDate2 & " Rtns"
        'do Stuff

Next mark
```

End Sub

Comment: The only problem with the code that I posted above is that it seems to be very slow.  so I"m going to try what you all recommended.